# Cause test failure from pytest autouse fixture

Tags: unit-testing, pytest, fixtures

`pytest` allows the creation of fixtures that are automatically applied to every test in a test suite (via the `autouse` keyword argument). This is useful for implementing setup and teardown actions that affect every test case. More details can be found in [the pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#autouse-fixtures-xunit-setup-on-steroids).

In theory, the same infrastructure would also be very useful for verifying post-conditions that are expected to exist after each test runs. For example, maybe a log file is created every time a test runs, and I want to make sure it exists when the test ends.

Don't get hung up on the details, but I hope you get the basic idea. The point is that it would be tedious and repetitive to add this code to each test function, especially when `autouse` fixtures already provide infrastructure for applying this action to every test. Furthermore, fixtures can be packaged into plugins, so my check could be used by other packages.

The problem is that it doesn't seem to be possible to cause a test failure from a fixture. Consider the following example:

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def check_log_file():
    # Yielding here runs the test itself
    yield

    # Now check whether the log file exists (as expected)
    if not log_file_exists():
        pytest.fail("Log file could not be found")
```

In the case where the log file does not exist, I don't get a test failure. Instead, I get a pytest error. If there are 10 tests in my test suite, and all of them pass, but 5 of them are missing a log file, I will get 10 passes and 5 errors. My goal is to get 5 passes and 5 failures.

So the first question is: is this possible? Am I just missing something? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22638709/4312739) suggests to me that it is probably not possible. If that's the case, the second question is: is there another way? If the answer to that question is also "no": why not? Is it a fundamental limitation of `pytest` infrastructure? If not, then are there any plans to support this kind of functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In pytest, a `yield`-ing fixture has the first half of its definition executed during setup and the latter half executed during teardown. Further, setup and teardown aren't considered part of any individual test and thus don't contribute to its failure. This is why you see your exception reported as an *additional error* rather than a test failure.

---

On a philosophical note, as (cleverly) convenient as your attempted approach might be, I would argue that it violates the spirit of test setup and teardown and thus even if you *could* do it, you shouldn't. The setup and teardown stages exist to support the execution of the test—not to supplement its assertions of system behavior. If the behavior is important enough to assert, the assertions are important enough to reside in the body of one or more dedicated tests.

If you're simply trying to minimize the duplication of code, I'd recommend encapsulating the assertions in a helper method, e.g., `assert_log_file_cleaned_up()`, which can be called from the body of the appropriate tests. This will allow the test bodies to retain their descriptive power as specifications of system behavior.

Comment: I suppose this answers the question as asked, but what I really want to know is whether there is a way to automatically apply pre- and/or post-conditions to some or all tests in a test suite. On the face of it, it seems like `autouse` fixtures could be used for such a purpose, but you have pointed out that this is not the case. Maybe I should create another, better question.

Comment: In pytest? None that I’m aware of, no.

Comment: Again, even if you could, I’d question whether you should (albeit for a different reason than that stated in my answer). What are these conditions you wish to assert repeatedly?

Comment: The actual use case is for a plugin that detects whether any file handles remain open after any particular test has ended. Currently we're forced to simply cause errors when an open file is found since `pytest` doesn't appear to provide a mechanism that behaves as I've described.

Comment: As in, a file handle opened by the test? That is, are you trying to make sure that tests are properly cleaning up after themselves? If that's the case, I'd argue that an error is more appropriate than a failure anyway, as a failure is meant to indicate that the *system under test* does not meet acceptable standards; what you're describing sounds more like an evaluation of *the tests themselves*.

Comment: Either way, if you're trying to write a plugin, I recommend you use the official "runtest" hooks: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html#generic-runtest-hooks. Fixture functionality in pytest is implemented as a plugin. By using `autouse` fixtures, you are indirectly using those official hooks, but in a far less obvious way.

Comment: I'm not trying to make sure the tests are cleaning up after themselves. I'm trying to make sure the code under test (which involves some fairly complex IO machinery) is cleaning up file handles as expected. So it makes sense to have test failures instead of errors. However, it sounds like `pytest_runtest_call` or `pytest_runtest_teardown` might be good options, so thanks for the hint.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want every test to assert this behavior, as opposed to a subset of tests dedicated to it?

Comment: Mostly because any given test may use this IO functionality, and so running the open files test against every test case allows for a lot of coverage that would be difficult to get otherwise. Also because this is a plugin that is provided for use by other packages that may have similar testing requirements. The open files test is activated by a command line flag, so it doesn't run by default.

Comment: Disagree. Philosophically speaking, a test should be dependent on your setup method in order to perform itself(otherwise its not setup) and hence if setup fails, the tests should be skipped.

Comment: @ShivamMishra I don't think anyone's arguing that the tests should still execute if setup fails.

Comment: @IanLesperance If I am reading between the lines of OP, I think if pytest by default would have skipped tests in case these setup fails, it would have been probably unncesary to do what he is asking for. OP correct me if I am wrong. If this is indeed what you want check out pytest-dependency. I just thought the answer should include that. I felt that answer is trying to suggest that setup should have no say in tests whatsoever.

Comment: @ShivamMishra I believe they want them to be reported as "failures" instead of additional "errors." I think marking them as "skipped" would actually be further from what they desire, which is to effectively use fixtures as a supplementary prefix to the test body.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it isn't possible to tell `pytest` to treat errors in particular fixture as test failures.

I also have a case where I would like to use fixture to minimize test code duplication but in your case [pytest-dependency](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-dependency/) may be a way to go.

Moreover, test dependencies aren't bad for non-unit tests and be careful with `autouse` because it makes tests harder to read and debug. Explicit fixtures in test function header give you at least some directions to find executed code.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using context managers for this purpose:

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def directory_that_must_be_clean_after_use():
    directory = set()
    yield directory
    assert not directory

def test_foo():
    with directory_that_must_be_clean_after_use() as directory:
        directory.add("file")
```

If you absoulutely can't afford to add this one line for every test, it's easy enough to write this as a plugin.

Put this in your `conftest.py`:

```py
import pytest

directory = set()

# register the marker so that pytest doesn't warn you about unknown markers
def pytest_configure(config):
    config.addinivalue_line("markers", 
            "directory_must_be_clean_after_test: the name says it all")

# this is going to be run on every test 
@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_call(item):
    directory.clear()
    yield
    if item.get_closest_marker("directory_must_be_clean_after_test"):
        assert not directory
```

And add the according marker to your tests:

```py
# test.py
import pytest
from conftest import directory

def test_foo():
    directory.add("foo file")

@pytest.mark.directory_must_be_clean_after_test
def test_bar():
    directory.add("bar file")
```

Running this will give you:

```
fail.py::test_foo PASSED
fail.py::test_bar FAILED
...
>           assert not directory
E           AssertionError: assert not {'bar file'}

conftest.py:13: AssertionError
```

You don't have to use markers, of course, but these allow controlling the scope of the plugin. You can have the markers per-class or per-module as well.